# view-models structure as foundation for similar kind of applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here by similar I mean to say that my applications has set of questions with 5/6 pages. The types of the properties that I am going to use will be same for all my apps. the only thing that will change is the order where the question appears like page -1/2/3/..

I have created some base types so that the same kind of apps will use those base types where most of the generic validations will be defined using data attributes.

as you can see in the image: [image]

Now, I will have to create viewmodels for every individual views. The viewmodels will be able to use those base types in the form of properties and some app specific validations will be defined in the same viewmodel.

I have thought about this structure for all my apps because I would then be repeating the same stuff again and again. I understand that every view should have its own viewmodel. So, I will reference the base type assembly and create separate viewmodels for app taking only the types that I need for specific view.

Is this a good way to step ahead as I want to have a foundation for all my apps?

Comment: I am not able to see the image! I have uploaded it from my pc anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, it looks good to me

Long answer:

It is a good idea to have a base abstract ViewModel that can be reused. I'd say you probably want to actually have more than 1.

One called ViewModelBase or BaseViewModel that contains everything specific to ViewModels, like the implementation of INotifyPropertyChange. This case class typically also implements IViewModel interface to indicate it's a ViewModel. And then a base class for each one of your business logic domains (in your case your set of questions/answers) where you set up common business logic

For validation if let's say, you are implementing IDataErrorInfo, you can use implement it in the most general class possible, the one that has the properties to validate. Typically some will happen in the base class, some in the derived classes

For each of your views you can select the specific ViewModel you want to use. Sometimes this will be quite light thanks to the inheritance. You can also look into reusing the Views dividing the parts in UserControls (and complementing with styles).